# display most commented posts last month wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display most commented posts of certain category last month.
This is my code for now, I cant figure out what is wrong here, any ideas?

```
<?php 
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
                }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'cat' => 2, 'orderby' => 'comment_count date', 'order'=> 'DESC' ));

    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
                ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                    echo get_the_title();
                    // and rest of content   
    endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

edit: p.s. btw I am using Vkontakte Api plugin for my comments. May be the problem is here, because this code actually works fine on other site. But, get_comments_number() shows the correct number, why then orderby => comment_count doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use [`date_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters), for this.

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => [
        [
            'year' => date('Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . " -1 month")),
            'month' => date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . " -1 month"))
        ]
    ],
    'orderby' => 'comment_count',
    'order' => 'DESC'
];
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
//$posts = get_posts($args);
//print_r($posts);
```

---

The MySQL query will be for getting the popular post of last month will be: (*assuming `NOW()` = 13 Feb 2017*)

```
SELECT
    posts.ID,
    posts.post_title,
    posts.post_date
FROM
    wp_posts AS posts
WHERE
    YEAR (posts.post_date) = 2017
AND MONTH (posts.post_date) = 1
AND posts.post_type = 'post'
AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY
    posts.comment_count DESC
LIMIT 0, 3;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Dolohov: can you run the MySQL and let me if you are getting any post or not? just replace the table prefix with yours.

Comment: i am getting them. but not sorted by comment_count. btw I added some more info yesterday, idk if you noticed or not

Comment: are getting ANY post by `WP_Query`? if so then I have to check with the plugin.

Comment: yes, im getting posts by queries, and even comments number are correct. but for some reason it won't sort posts by comment_count